# YUI Testing Mocks - Can I verify a method is called 3x with 3 different values?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, yui

I am using the latest version of YUI Test for testing my project.

I have a situation where I create a Mock with method Foo.  I expect that Foo will be called three times.  The first time, it will be called with value "A", the second time, it will be called with value "B", and the third time, it will be called with value "C".  The third time it is called, it should return true.

Here is an example of what I would like to write, however this doesn't appear to work, and only the last condition is validated.

```
var mock = Y.Mock();
Y.Mock.expect(mock, { method: "foo", args: ["A"] });
Y.Mock.expect(mock, { method: "foo", args: ["B"] });
Y.Mock.expect(mock, { method: "foo", args: ["C"], returns: true });
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source, it seems that the code stores a map keyed off the method name, so there can only be one expectation per method name.  You should probably file an enhancement request, since your use case is pretty common.